# Matlab Sparse function v.s. Python Scipy.sparse library

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am translating Matlab code into Python environment, and now handling with sparse function in Matlab. I know that we have the library called `scipy.sparse` and the one of them such that `csc_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])`.

However, when I check those computed from `scipy.sparse` library, they don't match the one from Matlab.
I have big data sized of 1693872 called `Ig` (1693872,), `Jg`(1693872,), and `K_dummy` (1693872,), where `K_dummy(Ig(i),Jg(i)) = K_dummy(i)`.

I have already check all the variables, `Ig`, `Jg`, `K_dummy` with Matlab and matches perfectly. Do you guys have any idea that I have to consider other aspects?

Here is my sample code in python and Matlab, respectively as references:

```
K = csc_matrix((K_dummy.flatten('F'),(Ig.flatten('F')-1,Jg.flatten('F')-1)),shape=(noDofs,noDofs))

K = sparse(Ig(:),Jg(:),K_dummy_python(:),noDofs,noDofs);
```

where `K_dummy` is (18, 18, 5228) array, `Ig` is (324, 5228) array, `Jg` is (324, 5228) array, and `noDofs` is an int variable as 42442.

Comment: It's easiest to help if the example is small with values we can reproduce on our own machine.  While I've worked the MATLAB sparse years ago, I not have tried side by side creations (using Octave).  I have import Octave created sparse via `.mat` files.

Comment: I was tempted to create a sample in Octave, and then transfer values, both dense and sparse to `scipy` (via `io.loadmat`), but making something that captures the shape and order complexity is going to be more work than I'm up for at the moment.  What are differences?  Is the sparsity (location on nonzeros) correct?  Just differences in nonzero values?

Comment: The difference between them is the number of nonzero elements stored in the sparse matrix.... And, I have checked all the flattened indices, Ig, Jg and all correct.

Comment: There should be 1693872 nonzero elements (`M.nnz`, `nnz(M)`).  Possible exceptions - `K_dummy` has some 0 values, which one is removing, the other isn't.  Or there are some duplicates, that one is summing and the other isn't.  `scipy` has a `M.eliminate_zeros()` method to use if processing has left zeros behind.  Summing duplicates is the norm for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Octave:

```
>> data=[1,2;3,4];
>> I=[1,2,3,4];
>> J=[2,3,4,2];
>> M = sparse(I(:),J(:),data(:))
M =

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 4, cols = 4, nnz = 4 [25%])

  (1, 2) ->  1
  (4, 2) ->  4
  (2, 3) ->  3
  (3, 4) ->  2

>> full(M)
ans =

   0   1   0   0
   0   0   3   0
   0   0   0   2
   0   4   0   0

>> save -7 sparse1.mat data I J M
```

In `numpy` with `scipy.io` and `scipy.sparse`:

```
In [57]: d = loadmat('sparse1.mat')                                                              
In [58]: d                                                                                       
Out[58]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.2.2, 2020-01-26 19:36:04 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'data': array([[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]]),
 'I': array([[1., 2., 3., 4.]]),
 'J': array([[2., 3., 4., 2.]]),
 'M': <4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>}
```

And looking at the sparse matrix:

```
In [59]: d['M'].A                                                                                
Out[59]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 4., 0., 0.]])
In [60]: print(d['M'])                                                                           
  (0, 1)    1.0
  (3, 1)    4.0
  (1, 2)    3.0
  (2, 3)    2.0
```

And recreating the matrix

```
In [61]: M1 = sparse.csc_matrix((d['data'].flatten('F'), 
                (d['I'].astype(int).flatten('F')-1, 
                 d['J'].astype(int).flatten('F')-1)))                                                        
In [62]: M1                                                                                      
Out[62]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [63]: M1.A                                                                                    
Out[63]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 4., 0., 0.]])
In [64]: print(M1)                                                                               
  (0, 1)    1.0
  (3, 1)    4.0
  (1, 2)    3.0
  (2, 3)    2.0
```

With a newer `numpy/scipy` I had to convert the indices to integer (they've gotten pickier about floats as indices).  But the flattening seems to work fine.

You have an added dimension in all those variables, which I was too lazy to recreate.  Flattening that correctly might be causing your problems.